# How to serialize requests Response object as HAR

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, python-requests, har

I want to serialize a [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) `Response` object as json, preferably in [HAR](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) format.

```py
import requests
resp = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')

har = to_har(resp)  # <--- magic
```

but couldnt find anything online with my google-fu powers.

it seems that all data exist on the `Response` object, i hope i dont need to implement the whole HAR spec and there exist some code/utility i can reuse.

a valid answer might give:
existing library or refer to a starting point if nothing exists so far for `python` and/or `requests`.

currently my simpler 3min solution (not HAR format) serialization to `Response` object looks like this (might be good start point if nothing exists):

```py
def resp2dict(resp, _root=True):
    d = {
        'text': resp.text,
        'headers': dict(resp.headers),
        'status_code': resp.status_code,
        'request': {
            'url': resp.request.url,
            'method': resp.request.method,
            'headers': dict(resp.request.headers),
        },
    }

    if _root:
        d['history'] = [resp2dict(h, False) for h in resp.history]
    return d
```

i post this as i think not only me struggle to serialize `Response` objects to json in general regardless of HAR format.

Comment: I think most people are happy with `resp.json()`, which may or may not comply with HAR, I don't know. You could also add fields to the `dict` returned by `resp.json()`.

Comment: resp.json() only works for json responses and only serialize the body of the response. you dont serialize the headers, url, request or redirect history. Its a different problem than im looking to solve. its actually deserializing the msg rather than serializing

Answer (score 2):

> currently my simpler 3min solution (not HAR format) serialization to Response object looks like this (might be good start point if nothing exists):

Looks like this is the best solution. I've checked every HAR-related library on PyPI and the only close solution I found (except [har2requests](https://github.com/louisabraham/har2requests)) is [marshmallow-har](https://pypi.org/project/marshmallow-har/). Unfortunately, `marshmallow_har.Response.__schema__` match the internal structure neither `requests.Response` nor `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse`. So, the solutions I see are:

1. Use the ad-hoc solution as you already do. To make sure the result has the correct structure, `marshmallow-har` can be used.
2. Make your own marshmallow schemas by providing `attribute` argument to the fields. I'd advise to fork and extend `marshmallow-har` but it uses factories and other strange magic and can't be easily extended. So, it's better to start from ground zero.

And consider open-sourcing your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working solution written in python from this project
https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/master/splash/har_builder.py

Following this working solution may provide you the clues you need